# In PHP, how to remove wrapping paragraph, but only if it's the only paragraph

Tags: php, html

How to remove the (in this case, useless) wrapping paragraph in cases like this:

```
<p>Only paragraph</p>
```

But to keep the string as it is when there is more than one paragraph involved:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

preg_replace would probably do the trick in here but only if you can handle regexps.. :/

Comment: I think you're just avoiding a different issue with this question. You should rework your CSS so it works with either way.

Comment: A `<p>` is never obsolete or useless. It defines a text paragraph, and that's what you have there. Even if it's the only one, it still **is** a paragraph!

Comment: It is obsolete, nor is it question of CSS, as the string will be injected into a container element, which can be anything from h2 to div and everything between. I really don't need paragraph tags within header element, aka. they are obsolete.

Comment: crappish: Why are you okay with two paragraphs in <h2>, but not with one? You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: Because those texts with multiple paragraphs won't be within headers. Can we please get back into the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, 2 test cases, $a and $b

```
$a = '<p>Only paragraph</p>';

$b = '<p>Only paragraph</p>
      <p>Only paragraph</p>
      <p>Only paragraph</p>';

// change the values to $a and then $b
if( count( explode('<p>', $a) ) == 2 ){
  $c = preg_replace('#</?p>#', '', $a);
}

if( isset( $c)) {
    var_dump( $c );
}
// 'Only paragraph'
```

You might need to add a trim() first as well.

Does not cater for malformed input eg

```
<p>para1 </p> para 2</p>
```

Comment: This works. :) But would rather see a preg_replace, as regular expressions, when done properly, are quite bomb proof solution. :)